# domain.com --> AJAX --> api.domain.com with Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've got an API set up on site: api.domain.com

Within the API are objects that operate on Users, Comments, Posts, etc. I also have a Facebook object that is currently set up to spit out

```
$facebook->getUser()
```

When I access my api in my browser, the correct ID of my facebook profile is returned. When I do an ajax call from subdomain-x.domain.com, the 0 is returned.

Is there any way to do this without running the Facebook PHP SDK on the main domains, as opposed to integrated with my API?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say that this is possible.

- When you create a Facebook session on api.domain.com, Facebook API itself sets cookies
- When you send an ajax request to another domain, you must take in consideration that Same Origin policy takes effect.
- When you send an ajax request to another domain, all cookies, which belongs to the specified domain are being sent.

Answer (score 1):

The facebook SDK by default uses PHP sessions to store the user info, the session cookie is not set across the whole domain.

You would probably have to change this using `session_set_cookie_params`, however if your writing an API then the user isn't going to be authorized through Facebook anyways so you wouldn't have access to cookies.